# Firebase Functions Backend Error: Cannot Import Library

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

Yesterday Night I deployed my functions and the deployment was successfull without any errors.

But when i tried to execute/call the function it throwed following error and logged in firebase console :

```
{ Error: Failed to import the Cloud Storage client library for Node.js. Make sure to install the "@google-cloud/storage" npm package. Original error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new FirebaseError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:43:28)
    at new Storage (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/storage/storage.js:65:19)
    at /srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:255:20
    at FirebaseApp.ensureService_ (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:376:23)
    at FirebaseApp.storage (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:253:21)
    at FirebaseNamespace.fn (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:292:45)
    at Object.exports.processCard (/srv/Files/process.js:157:24)
    at Busboy.bus.on (/srv/index.js:44:13)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:208:7)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'storage/missing-dependencies',
     message: 'Failed to import the Cloud Storage client library for Node.js. Make sure to install the "@google-cloud/storage" npm package. Original error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {' } }
```

after that i tried on more time ,to check if the error has gone, but then it throwed following:

```
Error: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initializeApp() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique name.
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:43:28)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:89:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:124:28)
    at FirebaseNamespaceInternals.initializeApp (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:68:23)
    at FirebaseNamespace.initializeApp (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:423:30)
    at Object.exports.processCard (/srv/Files/process.js:140:15)
    at Busboy.bus.on (/srv/index.js:44:13)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Busboy.emit (/srv/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:37:33)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'app/duplicate-app',
     message: 'The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initializeApp() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique name.' },
  codePrefix: 'app' }
```

I executed the function locally and everything was good function executed without any errors.

The weired part is that i never actully used `google-storage` library i use `firebase-admin` sdk to generate a `signedURL` and this is the function of generation of `singedURL`:

```
admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
        databaseURL: "urlToDatabase"
   });

function getSignedUrl(file) {
    console.time('URLGenerated ');
    let options = { action: 'read', expires: Date.now() + 5 * 60 * 1000 }; // 5min Expiration Time
    let bucketFileName = path.basename(file);
    return bucket.upload(file, { destination: `public/${bucketFileName}`})
        .then(() => {
            return bucket.file(`public/${bucketFileName}`).getSignedUrl(options)
                .then((urls) => {
                    fs.unlinkSync(file);
                    console.timeEnd('URLGenerated ');
                    return urls[0];
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    console.log('Link Generation Error' + e);
                });
        }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
}
```

In the second error it says that i've initialized admin twice but i don't think i've done that. I double checked evything and also tried emulator as i mentioned before.

and this is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.3.0",
    "busboy": "^0.3.1",
    "docx": "^5.3.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "gs4fb": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

It is 20 Hours now and my function is down. The functions is heart of my website.

Where is the problem ?

I've updated to latest version of `firebase-admin`, `firebase-functions` library and `firebaseCLI` not because i needed just because it was warning me everytime.

Comment: Please post where is path of storage and i can't find bucket assigning ?

Comment: @hey Ashish `bucket = admin.storage().bucket('myapp-web.appspot.com');` this is how i setup bucket

Comment: Isn't it somethng like : `gs://myapp-web.appspot.com` ?

Comment: no, we just need to pass the bucket name not the url to it. and the error is about app initialization not bucket.

Comment: it is logging two errors first is 'Cannot import Library' and second is 'Multiple Initialization' The Library part i found weird because i never actually asked for it. and same for app initialization.

Comment: Did you save the import with `--save` ? The first error occurs because you did not update the `package.json` file.

Comment: I never actually required that !!! i don't know what happened with latest update. I think the problem is related to bucket call maybe.

Comment: I removed `initialize.app({..})` and it returned `The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.'` So i am not calling it twice that's for sure.

Comment: @Ashish in the main Error `cannot import library` at the end it saying unexpected token {' so it could be error in the cloud library itself. but it's working in emulators though.

Comment: Try to reinstall the library with suffix as `--save` which will save the library in package.json

Comment: package.json includes the library. see OP package.json section. i saw the package.json file at GCS and the library was indeed there in the package.json file. I don't why firebase guys not taking the look into the question. I posted this 12 hours before and reposted the question still no officials here.

Answer (score 2):

Latest version of `firebase-Admin` was causing the error. Rolled back to `8.13` and everything was on track.

Seriously **Never Update to latest if NOT REQUIRED**.

Comment: Did you report the bug in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues? If so, a link to the github issue is always interesting.

Comment: Nope I didn't, i actually don't use github.